# Ошибка проверки платежа paypal

Tags: yii2, paypal

Got Http response code 500 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-*********************/execute

Может кто знает из-за чего данная ошибка. Не так давно все прекрасно тестировалось и никто ничего не менял. Сегодня тестил и вот результат, это после оплаты тестовой на запрос проверки. Проект на yii2. 
Кусок кода

```
$apiContext = new ApiContext(
        new OAuthTokenCredential(
            '***',     // ClientID
            '***'      // ClientSecret
        )
    );

    $payerId = $_GET['PayerID'];
    $paymentId = $user->paypal;
    $payment = Payment::get($paymentId, $apiContext);
    $execution = new PaymentExecution();
    $execution->setPayerId($payerId);
    try {
        $result = $payment->execute($execution, $apiContext);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash(
            'error',
            'Платёж не был совершён'
        );
        return $this->redirect('index');
    }
```

Comment: Ну а в логи фреймворка что пишет? Так же должно написать чем вызвана ошибка

Comment: Честно сказать, что на страницу, что в логи, то что оно кидает мне ни о чём не говорит(( Отчего эта ошибка ума не приложу, все в соответствии с примером да и работало все октябрь и пол ноября пока делал проект. А тут сегодня сдавались и вот сюрприз...
$result = $payment->execute($execution, $apiContext); - в этой строке ошибка

Comment: Не особо понимаю но сново все заработало. Почему - загадка до сих пор!